# How to convert htm file to text file as open it with IE then copy+paste

Tags: javascript, c#, html, xml, xslt

I have `hello.htm`、`hello.xml`、`hello.xsl` in the same folder, then I can open `hello.htm` with IE to see the result page, but since I don't really care what the color,font,format or whatever looks like, I just want the pure text, how can I using C# to creat a text file as I opened `hello.htm` and copy+paste the content to it? here's my `hello.htm` code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <TITLE>sample</TITLE>
  <SCRIPT language = "javascript">
     function init()
     {
        var srcTree = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
        srcTree.async=false;
        // You can substitute other XML file names here.
        srcTree.load("hello.xml"); 

        var xsltTree= new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
        xsltTree.async = false;
        // You can substitute other XSLT file names here.
        xsltTree.load("hello.xsl");

        resTree.innerHTML = srcTree.transformNode(xsltTree);
     }
  </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY onload = "init()" >
   <div id="resTree"></div>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: In what context do you use C#, a console application, a Windows Forms application (where you have WebBrowser control), an ASP.NET application? And does that XSLT file `hello.xsl` contain any extension code specific to MSXML or could you execute it within the .NET framework and with `XslCompiledTransform`? Is the HTML always as simple as a `div` where the result of the XSLT transformation is inserted or can there be other static content in the HTML you also want to copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use webclient download string :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should choose another program to open the file if you want to see the text?

If you are on windows and you click it with your right mouse button there should be an entry "open with" there you can select another program. As an example, the "editor" pre-installed in windows.